# What wrong in my code? My intent was to position the cubes all over the view space

Tags: render, webgl, three.js

```
var container, stats;
            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var arr = new Array();
            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.z = 1000;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );

                for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) 
                {

                    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff );

                }

                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } );

                for ( var i = 0; i < 20; i ++ )
                {

                    arr[i] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                    arr[i].position.set( Math.random() * scale, Math.random() * scale, Math.random() * scale ); 
                    scene.add( arr[i] );

                }

                renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );              
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() 
            {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() 
            {               
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }
```

My intention was to position the number of cubes allover the view space based on the number provided in for loop. But that doesn't seems to work here and in fact I see whole blank white screen. I even couldn't see fps on top left corner. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn how to use a debugger and/or inspect the console for errors.

You have to declare the variable `scale` and assign it a value.

```
var scale = 500;
```

You also have to include the Stats library, as in:

```
<script src="Stats.js"></script>
```

Please do not be too quick to ask for help. There are plenty of examples for you to learn from.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I included stats.js in my original code, but I didn't mention the included libraries. Though your snippet scale=500; helped me. But yet I couldn't see single cube on the canvas. Am I doing something wrong with camera position?

Comment: The code works on my machine. You could add `camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( scale/2, scale/2, 0 ) );` if you want. Enter that line right after setting the camera position.

Comment: If you want, you can also have a different camera position: `camera.position.set( scale/2, scale/2, 1000 );`